# Dump PostgreSQL table and all referenced data

Tags: postgresql

My objective is to dump all the schema but only some data for specific tables.

However, when I'm doing `pg_dump -t table_name`, this only dumps the data of `table_name` without dumping any referenced data from other tables (foreign keys).

What's the easiest solution to retrieve both the data of `table_name` and all the referenced data? Of course I only want referenced data to be dumped and not the whole data of referenced tables.

edit: I forgot to mention that I also want, in certain cases, to be able to retrieve all the data that references a row (the other way around).

Comment: Which version of postgres are you running atm?

Comment: it's postgresql 12

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of doing it:

```
pg_dump -t table_name

--Get only schema definition of referenced table

pg_dump -t other_table -s

--In psql to get only data referenced in child table.

\copy (select * from other_table where ref_key in (select distinct on(ref_fk) ref_fk from table_name)) to 'referenced_data.sql';
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm currently doing. I was just hoping that I won't have to do it by hand because I'll need to do that for multiple tables.

Comment: Well `pg_dump` is not going to do this for you. You will need to to do some variation of the above.